# When does an STL container inside a function keep its data in C++?

Tags: c++, vector, containers

I have a function that stores a list of primes in a vector container. At each call of the function, the container size remains the same or grows.

```
bool prime(int n)
{
    ...
    static vector<int> v;
    vector <int>::iterator Iter;
    ...
    v.push_back(n);
}


int main()
{
    int num = 0;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; ++i) {
      if (prime(i)) {
        ++num;
    }
}
```

I don't know why the storage works in the example. Is this program dependent?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What part "doesn't work"? Is your vector `v` being cleared somehow and you're wondering why?

Comment: vector `v` in this example is not cleared. I modified my question - sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It works because the variable is static:

```
   static vector<int> v;
// ^^^^^^
```

When you declare a variable like this inside a function it means the variable lives across function calls.

Technically this is a "Static Storage Duration" (SSD) object. These objects last as long as the program. Most SSD objects are created before main() is called. **BUT** in the case of function static variables they not created until the function is called the first time.